# Printing PDF files in landscape instead of portrait to get addition space for note taking

Tags: pdf, printing

Is there a way to print PDF in note-taking friendly way e.g I would like to print PDF file in landscape mode so that half of a page is effectively a PDF file and another half of the page is blank.

Can I do it on a Mac?

This is what I have now - text is centered, while I would like to increase font size and text to be moved all the way to the left to free half a page for notes. I know that increasing font size I can achieve with scaling, but I do not know how to move it all the way to left.

[image]

Comment: Have you just tried printing in Landscape, or two pages per sheet? Yes, there are ways to adjust prints to leave room for notes, but your question is quite broad. What have you tried so far? How has it worked or not worked? What specifically are you looking for? Please use the EDIT button to add context and information to your question to make both more clear and more narrow and focused.

Comment: @music2myear sure, will update

Comment: @music2myear updated

Comment: You may have to create blank pages between each page of content, and then to the two-pages-on-one-page printing method. What you're looking for is not a default option on any standard print dialog I'm familiar with.